# Retrieving items from SQL based on closest available time with different values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Current database structure is:
Table: `fxRates`
Fields: `createdOn`, `Value`

I also have a `List<string> fxLookupList` and each `string` object can correspond to a `fxRate` value property.

What I am trying to do is get all the fxRates that contain any item with the same `Value` from `List<FxLoopUp>` by doing something along the lines of `.Where(fx => fxLookUpList.Contains(fx.Value))`

However, since fxLookupList has multiple values, I can't figure out how to get all `fxRates` having the closest previous or matching today's date given that these should contain all values from `fxLookupList`.

Appreciate the help!

## Some explanation (Note that Today, Yesterday, etc are actually DateTime values)

```
Data Source:
------------------------------
TODAY                   TEST
YESTERDAY               HELLO
YESTERDAY               HI
YESTERDAY               HELLO
BEFORE YESTERDAY        HEY
BEFORE YESTERDAY        HI
A WEEK AGO              HELLO
A WEEK AGO              HEY

Assuming fxLookUpList will have "HELLO" and "HI";

Output =>
YESTERDAY | HELLO
YESTERDAY | HI

Assuming fxLookUpList will have "HEY" and "HI";

Output =>
YESTERDAY | HELLO
BEFORE YESTERDAY | HEY

Assuming fxLookUpList will have "TEST" and "HEY";

Output =>
TODAY | TEST
BEFORE YESTERDAY | HEY
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little confused by the last two paragraphs in combination with your title. Are you looking to retrieve the date whereby value equaled or was closest to a given value? Perhaps you could please include some example data and your expected result?

Comment: Hello @GeorgeKerwood, thanks for answering. I am trying to retrieve all fxRates from the database containing any of the items in fxLookupList and having a createdOn date either today or the earliest possible (from DateTime.UtcNow).

Comment: I think what you need is [groupby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) and then from each group order by date and select the latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am slightly having to guess because of the wording of the question, but if I'm understanding correctly, I believe this will do it:

```cs
    fxRates
        .Where(fx => fxLookUpList.Contains(fx.Value) && fx.createdOn <= today)
        .GroupBy(fx => fx.Value)
        .Select(fxGrp => fxGrp.OrderByDesc(fx => fx.createdOn).FirstOrDefault());
```

The `.Where()` obviously filters down to just values in `fxLookupList`.  At this point, the result set will contain multiple records for the same value with different `createdOn` dates, and if I'm understanding the question correctly, you just what the most recent of each value that is on/before today's date. So we also filter the `.Where` to filter on `cratedOn <= today`, where `today` is expected to be DateTime variable containing the exact time to filter on (didn't want to assume exactly what that means but you could also just write DateTime.UtcNow)

Following this, we `.GroupBy` value, so that each Grouping set will contain all the fxRates for a given Value with all dates before today (was already filtered in the .Where).

Finally, we project (`.Select`) out the most recent date by ordering the above grouping descending by `createdOn`, taking the `.FirstOrDefault()` to give you the most recent item (again already filtered to <= today).

Finally note that logically we would use `.First()` in the select, but can't because EF does not allow that in the query. Alternatively you could do a `.ToArray()` after the GroupBy and use `.First()` on the in-memory `.Select()`at that point.

Comment: See the edit; accidentally left a `.ToArray()` on the original answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer, I have a follow up question tho. `GroupBy` is throwing this error `System.InvalidOperationException: Client side GroupBy is not supported`. Any idea what could be the reason? The original question was simplified I have an `await` operator and using `EF Core`.

Comment: Removing the `await` operator, I am getting this `The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (f.Target), could not be translated`

Comment: Hrmm.... I am using regular ol' EF, and I can run a logically equivalent query without issue - must be a core thing..... How big are your sets? If not huge, you could do this client-side by changing the query to: 

`fxRates
        .Where(fx => fxLookUpList.Contains(fx.Value) && fx.createdOn <= today)
        .ToArray()
        .GroupBy(fx => fx.Value)
        .Select(fxGrp => fxGrp.OrderByDesc(fx => fx.createdOn).FirstOrDefault());`

Comment: This actually worked! Two concerns tho, you mentioned data sets 1) I have around a million record 2) What difference does `ToArray()` make?

Comment: That's a good concern. The difference is pretty major.  In my above query run against full framework, Entity Framework is able to compile the query to SQL and have the grouping and projection happen on the SQL server. My last comment changes this to be "client-side" grouping aka running on the machine running the code. So with a million records, that will mean a non-trivial amount of work is shifted to your machine (vs the sql server). I am not able to figure out a workaround at the moment but I would suggest seeing how to get around the `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: I would test just how expensive that operation is and decide from there whether it's OK to shift the work to client side.

Comment: Oh - and .ToArray() makes the query created before that call to be executed / for your records to be enumerated - so any code after the `.ToArray()` will now be working with the in-memory result set. Without `.ToArray()` no records are enumerated and the code is basically just building a SQL query under the hood to be sent to / executed by SQL only once an enumeration of the final result set is performed.

Comment: Does it help that were already filtering the data set with `.Where` clause? Because this automatically narrows down my set to ~100 records since i'm looking for a close date.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I misunderstood. Yes, in that case, then the in-memory operations will only be performed on 100 records. It's only if the `fxLookupList` contains a very large set that you will be performing operations with a large in-memory set, since the filtering will happen on the SQL side in the `.Where()`.

Comment: `fxLookupList` will have at most 3 records. - Thanks for the your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just extend the `Where` method to have only those values which were created before `today`

```
.Where(fx => fxLookUpList.Contains(fx.Value) && fx.createdOn <= DateTime.UtcNow)
```

Or you could also order them desc to get the closest:

```
.Where(fx => fxLookUpList.Contains(fx.Value) && fx.createdOn <= DateTime.UtcNow).OrderByDescending(fx => fx.createdOn)
```

Comment: This is getting there but not quite right; it will return multiple items with the same `Value` that were created before today; OP only wants the first.